# I have to change my databasefrom MySQL to postgreSQL in django, but its not working

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have to change my databasefrom MySQL to postgreSQL in django. But postgreSQL is not installing .

Error while installing postgreSQL using commands-

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get purge postgresql*
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

At terminal-

```
(jango)dc@dc-comp-4:~/website$ sudo apt-get install postgresql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

but its not working.how can i do this.and what changes i have to made. Plz help

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/42050

Comment: I visited that link and run all the commands but some error coming. Plz help .i am adding that to my question.

Comment: @ Selcuk sir plz give me some solution, i am getting frustated for 5 hours. Thanks in Advance

Comment: try: `$ sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev`

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: How about: `sudo apt-get autoclean $$ apt-get clear cache`
followed by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` then `sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev`

Comment: in command apt-get clear cache  giving error-E: Invalid operation clear

Comment: try: `sudo apt-get clean`

Comment: Still not working Error-   E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the download directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71678/discussion-between-rahul-satal-and-brandon).